# Wildcard for files in sub-directory in NMAKE

Tags: makefile, nmake

How could one make a wildcard dependency like `boot/*.inc` work in NMAKE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, with VS 2017:

```
>type makefile
mytarget : boot\*.inc
        !@echo $?

>dir/b boot
one.inc
two.inc

>nmake
boot\one.inc
boot\two.inc
```

The on-line documentation for NMAKE provided by Microsoft is simply awful.

In contrast, the older 59-page PDF document entitled *Chapter 16: Managing Projects with NMAKE* is vastly superior. It appears to agree with the current online version (an errata would be nice!). But it is surprisingly hard to find via Google; three possible links are:

- [http://www.engr.iupui.edu/~dskim/downloadable/reference_Nmake.pdf](http://www.engr.iupui.edu/%7Edskim/downloadable/reference_Nmake.pdf)
- https://www.scribd.com/document/19344397/Managing-Projects-With-NMAKE
- https://cld.pt/dl/download/4275816b-59bc-4fe9-96a3-f2c7a24e9246/GnuCOBOL/MISC/Manuals%20%26%20Guides/Visual%20Studio%20%26%20SDKs/Managing%20Projects%20with%20NMAKE.pdf?download=true

A good way to find them via certain search engines: `"Mike Eddy" nmake MSGRIDA1.DOT filetype:pdf`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :) Strange indeed, but I guess you've linked me some kind of rare jewel then ^_^.

Comment: BTW, _Chapter 16: Managing Projects with NMAKE_ does not include the [Batch-Mode Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/batch-mode-rules?view=vs-2017) feature.

Comment: BTW, an aside in the answer states "an errata would be nice!". I am starting to include some _errata_ here in the comments. If we get enough comments, maybe we could copy them to a new question/answer.

Comment: BTW, Some nmake command line options are now different, There are some new runtime switches: `/G`, `/U`, and `/Y`. The obsolete `/M` switch is gone, and `/V` is also gone.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey several related documents can be found. The document with the file name `LMAETC16.DOC` seems to be _just_ chapter 16 and the project name is "Environment and Tools" its footer. But if you look for the template name (`MSGRIDA1.DOT`) and author by file type, you can find one `LMAETAPA.DOC` (an appendix) which discloses the slightly more revealing project name "MASM Environment and Tools". Looking for that template and author name also yields some other useful documentation. Thanks for pointing it out!