# nmake throw error if variable is not defined

Tags: gnu-make, nmake

I have a makefile which I am running through nmake, as opposed to gnumake.

I have some code taken from a makefile intended to gnumake...

```
# out_repo = 

ifndef out_repo
$(error out_repo is not set)
endif
```

This does not work with nmake. Is there a way in nmake where I can have the same behaviour, where the make process will error out if a variable is not defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent code in NMAKE syntax would be:

```
# out_repo = 

!ifndef out_repo
!error out_repo is not set
!endif
```

See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54046754/318716 for a reference to older, more useful, NMAKE documentation.