# How to see built-in rules with nmake?

Tags: nmake

With GNU make one can say `make -npf /dev/null` (or on Windows `NUL`) in order to show the built-in rules. Where `-n` means `--just-print`, `-p` means `--print-data-base` and `-f` specifies the make file to use.

How can I achieve the same with `nmake`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `nmake -p` will, when entered in a folder with no makefile, give a list of environment variables, followed by a list of the built-in rules:

```
INFERENCE RULES:

.asm.obj::
        commands:       $(AS) $(AFLAGS) /c $<

.asm.exe:
        commands:       $(AS) $(AFLAGS) $<

.c.obj::
        commands:       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /c $<

.c.exe:
        commands:       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

.cc.obj::
        commands:       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /c $<

.cc.exe:
        commands:       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

.cpp.obj::
        commands:       $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) /c $<

.cpp.exe:
        commands:       $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $<

.cxx.obj::
        commands:       $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) /c $<

.cxx.exe:
        commands:       $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $<

.rc.res:
        commands:       $(RC) $(RFLAGS) /r $<

.SUFFIXES: .obj .asm .c .cc .cpp .cxx .f .f90 .for .rc
```

This is also at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/inference-rules.

See `nmake /?` for other switches, such as `-n`. Also see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54046754/318716) for some useful references to the older `nmake` documentation.